# Completely log out from the application in android

Tags: android, android-activity, logout

I have more than 3 screens and every screen has logout button on top, when i click the logout button, it should go to login page, and if i click the back button on login page, it should not go to the application and exit from application.

here I have tried the code for logout button click:

```
Intent in = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);
                    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    activity.startActivity(in);
```

Its working on more then 90 % of android mobile but its not working on few mobiles , Ex Samsung mini tab. and its not working on lower version of mobiles.

can any one guide me to over come this problem ?

Comment: what is actual happening.?

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is enough. try remove rest of the flags.

Comment: i tryed only with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP , but its working only few device , not all the device

Comment: i think you should use startActivityForResult for that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your current activity into a list `listContext` as metioned below.

```
listContext.add(Activity.this);
```

Try this method to finish all your activity.

```
public static List<Context> listContext = new ArrayList<Context>();


    public static void finishActivities() {

        for (Context context : listContext) {
            if(context!=null)
             ((Activity) context).finish();
        }
            listContext.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code on logout button activity:

```
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
```

and use this code on login screen :

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(setIntent);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable back button on your login screen

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //to nothing       }
```

Comment: on login screen if i press back button it should exit form the application so i cant disable the back button

Comment: ok so you create a flag variable in shared preferences and check it on activity on create is its true redirect to login screen and on logout button click set that flag to true and on login set it to false hope this may help you

Comment: @Segi I have also provided code for disabling back button, thats why its not comment

Comment: @Segi So now you can remove -1